# Routing issue in application using MVC/Durandal and located in IIS subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, durandal

I´m looking for a solution for my problem I mentioned in the title. 
First of all you need to know that I have **two MVC applications** published on an IIS. The first application is kind of a central management system so I set up a Site called "Management" in IIS. The second app is a MVC web shop embedded as application (subfolder) in Site "Management".

For the shop I created an MVC application using durandal.

Now it seems like I have a routing problem. When I enter the URL defined in Site "Management" I see the central management, which is completely right. The URL looks like:

```
http://mySite.com/
```

When I try to visit my shop I just go to the following URL:

```
http://mySite.com/Shop
```

This application only contains one *.cshtml* file which renderes the different pages of the shop using Durandal. This also works, but when I enter my credentials, Durandal seems to join the routing because it adds an "#/" to the URL. What happens then is that I´m redirected to the HomeController index view of my parent application (http://mySite.com). Thats what I don't want!

Can anyone of you help me in this issue?

I need to add that I don't have any problems locally when I run the shop so I guess the subfolder thing and/or durandal is the cause of this behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Yheeky

Comment: Can you explain what action entering your credentials should take? Maybe include the implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's the subfolder "Shop" that's causing this behavior. I had the exact same problem with the applications I was developing. Here's the solution I used. I feel like it's sort of a hack, but it does the job.

First, after digging into the RequireJS config documentation, I figured out how to pass on variables to a module in the `main.js` file.

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    ...
  },
  config: {
    'modules/routes': {
      subfolder: 'Shop'
    }
  }
});
```

I then created a `routes.js` module under an `/App/modules/` folder in the project whose sole responsibility it to construct URLs for the rest of my application. Within that module, I wrote a function that determines whether or not the script is running locally or on a web server. Based on that, it then uses the `subfolder` variable I passed it in the RequireJS config to construct the root URL the application will use for all routing.

```
define(['module'],
  function (module) {
    // if the application is being hosted on http://localhost, do not include the application name
    var domain = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
        root = (window.location.hostname !== 'localhost') ? domain + '/' + module.config().subfolder : domain;

    function getUrl(controller, action) {
      return (action) ? root + '/' + controller + '/' + action : root + '/api/' + controller;
    }

    return {
      getUrl: getUrl,
      cart: getUrl('Home', 'Cart'),
      ...
    }
});
```

Note that it's important that you pass in `'module'` in order to read the variable from the RequireJS config.