# Durandal App/main.js not found in IIS app

Tags: durandal

I've been developing an app with Durandal locally, and pushing to Azure, and all has been fine

however, I tried to add it to my local IIS for colleagues to preview to 
`http://yeps85228/gstt`, it doesn't get started, with this error:

```
GET http://yeps85228/App/main.js 404 (Not Found)
```

so, how can I reroute App to

```
http://yeps85228/gstt/App/main.js
```

so it's the relative path of the application

I've added the App and Scripts folders as IIS virtual folders from the root, so it runs for now, but is there a better way?

cheers

Comment: How get's main.js loaded? Make sure to use a relative path for data-main e.g. `data-main="app/main"` instead of data-main="/app/main".

Comment: Also if you are using ASP.NET MVC to host the app you can use data-main="@Url.Content("~/App/main")" to have the server construct a relative path.

Comment: My answer in this similar question may be of help to you: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542748/routing-issue-in-application-using-mvc-durandal-and-located-in-iis-subfolder/19566368#19566368).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deployment config for VS Durandal template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773144/deployment-config-for-vs-durandal-template)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Add the `base` tag at the beginning of your page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://yeps85228/gstt/" />
...
```

documentation for the `base` tag is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: I tried to mark my own as duplicate but yours hadn't been accepted or upvoted so I had to go the other way. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PeterWone- no worries